# CSS - display inline-block strange behaviour with text on new line

Tags: html, css

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sMyGV/2/) :

## CSS

```
div
{
    height:30px;
}

.prodotto_pulsante_testo_centrato
{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:120px;
}

.prodotto_pulsante_testo_numero
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:23px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-31px;
    bottom:-1px;
    background-color:green;    
}

.prodotto_pulsante_testo_titolo
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:23px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;  
    text-align:left;    
}
```

## HTML

```
<div>
    <span class="prodotto_pulsante_testo_centrato">
        <span class="prodotto_pulsante_testo_titolo">
            operativo
            <span class="prodotto_pulsante_testo_numero">4</span>                                    
        </span>
    </span>       
</div>    

<div>
    <span class="prodotto_pulsante_testo_centrato">
        <span class="prodotto_pulsante_testo_titolo">
            sportello operativo
            <span class="prodotto_pulsante_testo_numero">4</span>                                    
        </span>
    </span>       
</div>
```

the red boxes are `display:inline-block;`. The longest word in the boxes is "operativo", so I aspect they will be aligned to the same vertical line.

But, on second box, I have a new line on the text, cause of the 120px of the parent div, which push `prodotto_pulsante_testo_titolo` to a highest width.

Why this behaviour? I suppose that is correct : the same on Firefox and Chrome. It works as I aspect on IE :)

Comment: aspect -> expect ; `highest width` what does this mean ? how would you like it to work?

Comment: Do you want sportello operativo to be on one line or on two lines? If you want sportello operativo to be on one line you will have to increase it's parent div width. Like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/trickeedickee/sMyGV/4/

Comment: you can try with white-space:nowrap;

Comment: In fact I want two line if the widht is not enough... but aligned with the same vertical line

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/NBLuz/)

if you do this, put a < br />

the width of the red boxes then match.  without it The width of the second red box is extended because it contains two words which pushes out the width.  You happen to set a width that isn't wide enough to maintain both words on the same line.

```
sportello<br />operativo
```

Comment: can't add the <br>. The string is in one line! I won't to maintain the same line for the words...

Comment: Not sure if this behavior will be ok for what you are trying to accomplish, but if you set a min-wdith on .prodotto_pulsante_testo_titolo large enough for the content of either divs. Then the two will be the same size, which in turn will align them up vertically.